# make a single dimensional array multidimensional

Tags: php

I have a function that loops through an array and runs database operations within each loop.

```
function myfunc($array) {
    foreach($array as $a) {
        // db operations here
        echo $a["one"].'<br />';
        echo $a["two"].'<br />';
    }
}
```

but then sometimes, I have a single-dimensional array such as

```
$x = array(
    'one' => '1',
    'two' => '2'
);
myfunc($x);
```

however, it's falling to loop because there is nothing to loop over.

I get errors saying:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'one'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'two'
```

i know I could make the single dimensional array `$x[]` but that would mean I have to reset it to empty each time (`$x = array();`) - which isn't a problem but if it;s possible to loop over a single dimensional array, i'd rather do that

Comment: "but then sometimes, I have a single-dimensional array such as" <- if you know when it's the case, then simply pass `[$single_dimensional_array]` as parameter to your function.

Comment: or just use `if(isset($a["one"]))...`

Comment: @Jeto so like `myfunc([$array]);`?

Comment: @charlie That's right.

Comment: Genius! I'll give that a try in the morning 

Comment: @Jeto put that as an answer so I can mark it - works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you have only one entry, you'll want to wrap it into a array of one, like this:

```
myfunc([$array]);
```

Comment: I've just thought will this work for more than one entry too?

Comment: Well if you have more than one, then you probably already have an array of two. Otherwise, you can do `myfunc([$array1, $array2, $array3]);` for instance.